# RxJS operator like share(), but not preventing subscription from completion for secondary observers/subscriptions

Tags: rxjs

Which operator should I use to achieve a `share()` behaviour that will **not** prevent the observable from completion, if the main observer unsubscribes even if others are still subscribed. Similar to what is wired below using a `Subject`.

```
const shareSubject = new Subject<UpdateEvent<T>>();

  const additionalSubscription = asSynchronisedCollection$(cacheSubject.asObservable())
    .debounceTime(3000)
    .subscribe(() => {
      // do something in the secondary subscriber.
      // as opposed to how share() works, 
      // this observer shouldn't prevent the observable from completion
    });

 const mainSubscription = updateEvents$().do(
    (update) => {
      cacheSubject.next(update);
    },
    (e) => {
      cacheSubject.error(e);
    },
    () => {
      cacheSubject.complete();
    }
  )
  .subscribe(event => {
    // do something in the main observer
    // until this observer unsubscribes the subscription should not complete
  })
```

Calling `mainSubscription.unsubscribe()` will be passed to observable returned by `updateEvents$()` and will result in secondary subscriber receiving `onComplete()`

Calling `additionalSubscription.unsubscribe()` will not be passed to observable returned by `updateEvents$()` and will not result in main subscriber receiving `onComplete()`.

Is there an operator that can be used in that way? The >usage< would look similar to `.share()`

Comment: What do you mean by "main observer"?

Comment: By the "main observer" I mean the observer that manages the subscription lifecycle, and prevents the observable from completion.

Comment: Observers don't prevent the observable from completing. Observer just observer. It's the observable that completes.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't precise. I updated the example to reflect what I mean by "observer that prevents the observable from completion".

Comment: `share()` itself doesn't prevent the chain from completing. I think you'll need to make stackblitz demo showing what you want to achieve